# Can't create parallel database with parallel_tests with zeus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, zeus

i have an issus with zeus-parallel_tests and his initialization :

my gemfile :

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3"
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "rspec-its"
  gem "guard-rspec"
  gem "quiet_assets"
  gem "dotenv-rails"
  gem "parallel_tests"
  gem "zeus-parallel_tests"
end
```

then bundle, all right

my database.yml configuration :

```
connection: &connection
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  username: ********
  password: ********
  encoding: utf8
  min_messages: warning

development:
  database: app_development
  <<: *connection

test:
  database: app_test<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>
  <<: *connection

production:
  database: app_production
  <<: *connection
```

then zeus-parallel_tests init for create my custom_plan.rb and zeus.json
all right

but when i try to create my parallels databases (i have an i7 with 8 threads) i have a weird message :

```
> rake parallel:create
app_development already exists
app_development already exists
app_development already exists
app_development already exists
app_development already exists
app_development already exists
app_development already exists
app_development already exists
```

With parallel try to duplicate my development database ? i expected he duplicate my app_test database

```
> rake parallel:drop
> rake parallel:create
PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_database_datname_index"
DETAIL:  Key (datname)=(app_development) already exists.
: CREATE DATABASE "app_development" ENCODING = 'utf8'

and

/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-4.1.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_database_datname_index"
```

and i have only 1 app_test database and 1 app_development database after my manipulation..

Any idea ? 
i don't touch custom_plan.rb and zeus.json
zeus is ok
rspec is ok
Ruby = 2.1.3
Rails = 4.1.13

Comment: In your rails helper do you have that env variable at the very top setting it to test env?

Comment: yep :
on top of my rails_helper.rb =
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"

Comment: I don't have an answer, but we are experiencing a similar issue and it seems to be related to `dotenv-rails`. Do you have a `.env.development` or similar file?

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue using the `parallel_specs` gem (not the `zeus` one) - I believe it was trying to run in development environment. I am not sure if this is a problem in my app or in the gem, but I had to explicitly set the `RAILS_ENV` for this to work:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake parallel:setup
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake parallel:spec
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because of Spring, the `rake` command uses it. Try disabling it or [patching](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/wiki/Spring) it.